null modem emulator для GNU/Linux
Пишу программу для взаимодействия с устройством через COM-port.
Само устройство мне не доступно, поэтому встал вопрос об эмуляторе.
Для Windows есть com2com.
Есть ли подобные программы для Linux?

Можешь использовать /dev/ptmx вместо COM порта. Когда твоя программа подключится в папке /dev/pts создается файл со следующим псевдотерминалом, например, /dev/pts/4.
Твоя программа вместо ptmx получит открытый pty мастер. то что запишешь в него вылетит из парного pts. то что запишешь в pts вылетит в pty.
Можно выполнять операции установки скорости и подобное на этом псевдотерминале.
Найти слейв програмно можно через ioctl TIOCGPTPEER и получить путь к файлу через fcntl F_GETPATH
